# Why is "node output" error occurring in isight?

Tags: abaqus, isight

I used abaqus and loop component in isight.
But It's not working.
I tried changing the element type from CPS3 to CPE4R.
But the error continued to occur.
If you know how, please let me know.
Thank you.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhvSM.gif)

Comment: I want the parameter of input to be Sketch.

Comment: Please do not send images as links, you can embed them with the post. Concerning you question: I don't know how your input file was created (in general would be nice to have a short reproducible example of your actions which result in the error) but Abaqus doesn't have the keyword `*NODEOUTPUT` (without space) but it has `*NODE OUTPUT` (with space).

Comment: I don't know how to post a picture like you said. I want to run repeatedly using abaqus and loop componenet in isight. I'm going to use the sketch value for input of abaqus. But there was an error in isight that node set assembly was not defined. I think isight doesn't do re-mash. Do you know how to do it if it's possible? I'll give you my .cae and .odb files if you need them. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Here is how too format your post: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting.
About the question: sorry, but I've never worked with iSight, so I am not aware of error/bugs connected with it. I gave you a possible direction (a wrong keyword is generated in the input file), but it is up to you now to find what is triggering this error initially